# Get Date from Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: java, sql, datetime

I'm using Apache POI to read excel spreadsheets.  I would like to capture the date shown in the formula bar as opposed to the cell itself.

Doing the following:

```
System.out.println("Raw Value: " + cell.getRawValue());
System.out.println("Date Value: " + cell.getDateCellValue());
System.out.println("String Value " + cell.toString());
```

Yields

```
Raw Value: 40546
Date Value: Mon Jan 03 00:00:00 EST 2011
String Value: 03-Jan-2011
```

When I go to do an insert into a SQL table I am using a datetime field.  Is there any convient way to approach this such that I can pull directly from excel instead of using a SimpleDateFormater?

I am currently trying to do this, and without hardcoding it for this specified style, I don't know of a better way.

I have code for how I am doing it currently (not working because of SQL datetime format) if you would like to see it.

Thanks,
Mike

EDIT

So I should have clarified, I am updating the date value with a time value stored in a different cell in the form of 123450 where it is 24 hour time then minutes then seconds.  I am sub stringing this to be 12:34:50. I then append this value to the date and use date time for the SQL.

Comment: POI's Cell.getDateCellValue() returns a java.util.Date. You should be able to use that directly (or wrap in a java.sql.Timestamp) in your insert. The only reason it looks like "Mon Jan 03 00:00:00 EST 2011" is because println() implicitly calls the .toString() method of the parameter.

Comment: It should be noted that Excel stores a date as a floating-point value, where the integer portion is the day of the epoch, and the fractional part represents the time within the day.